Problem understanding p.68-70 of Hyperbolic Geometry by James W. Anderson
I have an understanding issue, reading pages 68-71 (chapter 2, 2.10 The geometry of the action of $Möb(\mathbb{H})$) in Hyperbolic Geometry by James W. Anderson. Here, we are looking for fixed points of a Möbius transformation $n$ of the form: $n(z)=\frac{\alpha \overline{z}+\beta}{\gamma \overline{z}+\delta}$, where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are all purely imaginary, with $\alpha \gamma-\beta \delta=1$.
Let $\alpha=ai, \beta=bi, \gamma=ci, \delta=di$, with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and write $z$ as $z=x+iy$, with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Fixed points of $n$ fulfill: $z=\frac{\alpha \overline{z}+\beta}{\gamma \overline{z}+\delta}$, we can write this to: $0=c |z|^2+dz-a\overline{z}-b=cx^2+cy^2+(d-a)x-b+i(d+a)y$.
I have problems with the case where $n$ is assumed to have no fixed points in the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z) >0\}$ and where $c=0$. Since $c=0$, one fixed point is $\infty$, but in addition the book says:" As we are interested in the case in which no solutions are in $\mathbb{H}$, we set $y=0$ and consider those solutions that lie in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. In the case in which $c=0$, we have two solutions, namely, $\infty$ and $\frac{b}{2d}$. In this case, $n$ takes the hyperbolic line $l$ determined by $\infty$ and $\frac{b}{2d}$ to itself and interchanges the two half-planes determined by $l$, but no point on $l$ is fixed by $n$, because $n$ has no fixed points in $\mathbb{H}$ by assumption. That is, $n$ acts as a glide reflection along $l$".
I don't understand why $\frac{b}{2d}$ should be a fixed point, clearly $\frac{b}{d-a}$ is a fixed point, so why should $a=-d$ ?
After that, the book also claims that: $n \circ B(z)=n(-\overline{z})=\frac{-\alpha z+\beta}{-\gamma z+\delta}=\frac{-az+b}{-cz+d}$ is loxodromic (see Wikipedia article for möbius transformation), so it should hold that $(-a+d)^2 < 0$ or $(-a+d)^2 > 4$, and I don't see why this should be the case when $a=-d$. Otherwise I would argue that $a+d \neq 0$, since if $a+d=0$, we can plug in for $y$ what we want and get solutions in $\mathbb{H}$. Furthermore $c=0$, so $-ad=1$, thus $a=-1/d$. Therefore, $(-a+d)^2=(1/d+d)^2 \geq 4$, with equality when $d=1$ and $a=-1$, but this can't be since $a+d \neq 0$.


The book has a mistake in computing the fixed point, that's all. You have the equation $\alpha \delta - \gamma \beta=1$, which becomes $ad-bc=-1$. If $c=0$ then $a=-1/d$, not $a=-d$.

Okay thank you, that's what I expected. It is one of the first math books I'm reading myself, so I wanted to ask if its okay to ask such questions here, whenever I suspect an error I get hung up on it for a long time. How casual are those minor errors in math books?

Yes, this is a good idea. You can also check if the author has a list of errata for his book. And, yes, such mistakes are quite common.
